# Instantiate generic repository dynamically and how to add entity base class to Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Following is the implementation of repository pattern using EF6. I want to use the generic repository in the following way thereby removing the need to create repository for every type

```
_unitOfWork.Repository(entityName).Insert(entityName)

public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    //--Search Operations
    IEnumerable<T> Get();
    T GetByID(object id);
    void Insert(T entity);
    void Delete(object id);
    void Delete(T entityToDelete);
    void Update(T entityToUpdate);
}
```

I have created a base class that all entities will inherit. The intent of this bases class is so that i can refer all entities with this base class.

```
public class IRepositoryEntity
{
}
```

Following is the Entity Framework generated code, I have inherited this entity from `IRepositoryEntity`

```
public partial class Client_Entity: IRepositoryEntity
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Client_Entity()
    {
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Following is the generic repository

```
public class GenericRepository<IRepositoryEntity> : IRepository<IRepositoryEntity> where IRepositoryEntity : class
{
    #region Private member variables...
    internal ConsularDB_March2016Entities Context;
    internal DbSet<IRepositoryEntity> DbSet;
    #endregion

    #region Public Constructor...
    /// <summary>
    /// Public Constructor,initializes privately declared local variables.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    public GenericRepository(ConsularDB_March2016Entities context)
    {
        this.Context = context;
        this.DbSet = context.Set<IRepositoryEntity>();
    }
    ///// <summary>
    ///// Public Constructor,initializes privately declared local variables.
    ///// </summary>
    ///// <param name="context"></param>
    //public GenericRepository()
    //{
    //    this.Context = context;
    //    this.DbSet = context.Set<IRepositoryEntity>();
    //}
    #endregion

    #region Public member methods...

    /// <summary>
    /// generic Get method for Entities
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public  IEnumerable<IRepositoryEntity> Get()
    {
        IQueryable<IRepositoryEntity> query = DbSet;
        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

Following is the `IUnitOfWork` interface and its implementation

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    #region Properties
    GenericRepository<Client_Entity> ClientRepository { get; }
    #endregion

    #region Public methods
    /// <summary>
    /// Save method.
    /// </summary>
    void Save();
    GenericRepository<IRepositoryEntity> Repository(IRepositoryEntity entity);
    #endregion
}

/// <summary>
/// Unit of Work class responsible for DB transactions
/// </summary>
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable, IUnitOfWork
{
    #region Private member variables...

    private March2016Entities _context = null;
    private GenericRepository<Client_Entity> _clientRepository;
    #endregion

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        _context = new March2016Entities();
    }

     #region Public member methods...
    /// <summary>
    /// Save method.
    /// </summary>
    public void Save()
    {
        try
        {
            _context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            var context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)_context).ObjectContext;
            var refreshobjects = _context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Select(c => c.Entity).ToList();
            context.Refresh(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.RefreshMode.StoreWins, refreshobjects);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {

            var outputLines = new List<string>();
            foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                outputLines.Add(string.Format("{0}: Entity of type \"{1}\" in state \"{2}\" has the following validation errors:", DateTime.Now, eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State));
                foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    outputLines.Add(string.Format("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"", ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage));
                }
            }
            System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(@"C:\errors.txt", outputLines);

            throw e;
        }

    }

    #endregion

    #region Implementing IDiosposable...

    #region private dispose variable declaration...
    private bool disposed = false;
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Protected Virtual Dispose method
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing"></param>
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("UnitOfWork is being disposed");
                _context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dispose method
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    #endregion
    #region GenericMembers
    Dictionary<string, GenericRepository<IRepositoryEntity>> repostories = new Dictionary<string, GenericRepository<IRepositoryEntity>>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Generic Repository method which checks the repository is available if not,
    /// it sets it up.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity">Entity</param>
    /// <returns>Repository to use.</returns>
    public GenericRepository<IRepositoryEntity> Repository(IRepositoryEntity entity)
    {
        string index = entity.GetType().ToString();

        if (!repostories.ContainsKey(index))
        {

            //Reflections to create the repoositiory if it is not needed.
            Type type1 = typeof(GenericRepository<IRepositoryEntity>);
            Type[] typeArgs = { entity.GetType() };

            Type constructed = type1.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
            object o = Activator.CreateInstance(constructed, this._context);

            //if (o is GenericRepository<IRepositoryEntity>)
            //{
            object genericRepo = (object)o;
            var rep = (GenericRepository<IRepositoryEntity>)genericRepo;
            //rep.Context = this._context;
            repostories.Add(index, rep);
            //}
        }
        return this.repostories[index];
    }
    #endregion  
}
```

I am trying to create a list of `GenericRepository` dynamically in the following function

```
public GenericRepository<IRepositoryEntity> Repository(IRepositoryEntity entity)
```

while creating the instance, it is throwing the following exception

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: GenericRepository`1[IRepositoryEntity] is not a GenericTypeDefinition. MakeGenericType may only be called on a type for which Type.IsGenericTypeDefinition is true.

I understand the exception, however not sure on how can I change the implementation so that i am able to achieve the desired functionality. Also how can I add `IRepositoryEntity` to EF model because it says it is not part of the model.

```
public void ValidateGenericEntityInsert(IRepositoryEntity entityName)
{
        IRepositoryEntity entity = (IRepositoryEntity)Activator.CreateInstance(entityName);
        _unitOfWork.Repository(entityName).Insert(entityName);

        // int generatedId = GetPropertyFromEntity(entity, en => en.Id);
        int generatedId = (int)GetPropertyFromEntity(entityName, "Id");

        Assert.That(generatedId, Is.GreaterThan(0));
}
```

Comment: See [Repositories On Top UnitOfWork Are Not a Good Idea](http://rob.conery.io/2014/03/04/repositories-and-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/) and rethink your architecture - does it *really* make sense to create `IRepository<T>` on top of the `DbSet<T>` which **already** is an implementation of the repository pattern?....

Comment: The repository declaration seems a little weird to me.  I would think that your generic repo should be declared as `GenericRepository<T>` with a `where` constraint specifying that T is an IRepositoryEntity.